# Marker animation trigger from parent composition

Tags: video, after-effects, after-effects-expressions

Is it possible to trigger animation from parent comp layer? I have been trying this expression with my basic coding skills but couldn't make it work.

```
n = comp("myparentComp").layer("myLayer").marker.key(time); 
if(time < marker.key(n).time){ n=n-1;
}
if(n==0){ n=1
}
t=time-marker.key(n).time;
thisProperty.valueAtTime(t)
```

Comment: Sounds definitely doable but I need some more data. What are you trying to "trigger"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally possible, but there are some problems with your expression.

```
n = comp("myparentComp").layer("myLayer").marker.key(time);
```

In this line `n` is going to return a marker key object. However the last part of the line uses the current time in the method `marker.key(time)`. This won't work. The `marker.key()` function expects an int referring to the number of the marker (1-indexed, so the first marker is `marker.key(1)`, because WTF adobe). A marker key has a `time` property, which is probably where you're getting confused. Also then you're treating `n` as if it's an integer, and you use a variable `marker` without declaring it or giving it a value.

If you want the animation to trigger on the first marker, it should look like this:

```js
var marker1time = comp("myparentComp").layer("myLayer").marker.key(1).time;
if(time < marker1time){ 
  t = 0; //hold the animation until the first marker
} else {
    t=time-marker1time; //will start at 0 at the point where time == marker1time
}
thisProperty.valueAtTime(t);
```

Some basic JS tutorials would probably help. I recommend the [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) ones, they're web-design focused, but almost all JS tutes are.

Comment: Nice thanks, it worked. I got another question, would that be possible to have this expression for the animation to react to every markers of `comp("myparentComp").layer("myLayer")` ? 

This one works for the markers on the layer but I can't make it work with the one you wrote. 

`n = marker.nearestKey(time).index; 
if(time < marker.key(n).time){ n=n-1;
}
if(n==0){ n=1
}
t=time-marker.key(n).time;
thisProperty.valueAtTime(t)`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean "have the animation react"?